# Why List<Integer> is not a subtype of `List<Number>` but is subtype of `List<? extends Number>`?

Tags: java

Why `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` but is subtype of `List<? extends Number>` ?

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
List<? extends Number> nums = ints;// <-- No Error
```

Answer (score -1):

A List is a list that guarantees that every of it's members is an integer. A List makes no such guarantee, it can be some other type.
On the other hand List does not make such a guarantee.