# Why is Foo<String> considered a subtype (extended) of Foo<? extends Object>?

Tags: java, generics

This is an extension of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891301/2775450).

> Note: This is not a duplicate of the following. [Why List is not a subtype of `List<Number>` but is subtype of `List<? extends Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25994445/2775450), nor any of the questions this has been marked duplicate of. Let me explain.

**The actual question was** (edited to remove unnecessary code),

```
void wildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? super Number>> list) {}

//... From some method.
    List<Pair<Object>> list = null;
    wildcardsMethod(list);
    // Error: wildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? super Number>>) is not applicable for the arguments (List<Pair<Object>>)
```

***The above doesn't work***.

And the answer given was **similar to** (if I have not misunderstood),

> `Pair<Object>` is a **subtype** of `Pair<? super Number>` and so it cannot be used in place of `<? super Pair<>>`.

I don't understand it in this context. I was thinking it's just a `Pair` object and we should be able to use it in place of both `<? extends Pair<>>` and `<? super Pair<>>`. But it doesn't work in the latter.

Can someone explain why it's considered to be a **subtype** thus limiting it to only `extends` and not `super`.

### EDIT:

To explain a little more, let's see why we will the method (considering [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2775450)),

```
void wildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? super Number>> list) {}
```

You will be using it to **add** a `Pair<Number>` object to the passed `list`.

In this case, `List<Pair<Object>>` is a valid list which can accept a `Pair<Number>` object.

***So, why is this not allowed?***

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `extends` and `super` in generics?

Comment: Isnt String a subtype of Object?

Comment: @Makoto, yes I do. But in this case, I am thinking `Pair<Object>` is not a subtype of `Pair<? super Number>`. It's the same type.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav, true.. But that doesn't mean Foo<String> should be a subtype of Foo<Object>. I edited the question to make a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the forest for the trees, and think that `List<Pair<Object>>` is the same as `List<? super Pair<? super Number>>`, when they are *not*.

`List<? super Pair<? super Object>>` declares that a list will contain either `Pair<Object>` or a *supertype* of `Pair<Object>`, which could be `Object` or some other ancestral class between `Object` and `Pair<T>`.  `List<Pair<Object>>` declares that **only** `Pair` objects or objects that can be considered a `Pair` will ever exist in that class.

The bounds are going in different directions.  You're implicitly getting `List<? extends Pair<? super Object>>` with the first declaration.

The only way you could reasonably do this is if the list you were passing in were also bound in a similar fashion.  That is, you would want to be passing in a `List<? super Pair<? super Number>>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "A is a subtype of B", what that means *by definition*, is that every object of type A is also an object of type B.  Now if you declare a variable with `Foo<? extends Object> x;`, that means that the objects that `x` can refer to are precisely those objects which are of type `Foo<something>` (where `something` extends `Object`).  Obviously, that includes objects of type `Foo<String>`.

So every `Foo<String>` is also a `Foo<? extends Object>` - so by definition, `Foo<String>` is a subtype of `Foo<? extends Object>`.

Likewise, every `Pair<Object>` is also a `Pair<? super Number>` - so by definition, `Pair<Object>` is a subtype of `Pair<? super Number>`.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about Makoto's answer for sometime I understood what it meant.

*Note: I am writing this answer in a format which I can easily understand for future reference (though his will be the accepted answer)*

Let's say we have the method in question defined like this (considering PECS),

```
void wildcardsMethod(List<? super Pair<? super Number>> list) {
    Pair<Number> pairOfNumbers = new Pair<Number>();
    list.add(pairOfNumbers);
}
```

and we are calling the method with this argument (***assuming it was allowed***),

```
List<Pair<Object>> listOfPairOfObjects = new ArrayList<Pair<Object>>();
wildcardsMethod(listOfPairOfObject);
```

Now, a `Pair<Number>` object is added to `listOfPairOfObjects`.

Also remember that the rules of **PECS only apply to** the `list` reference in `wildcardsMethod`  and not the `listOfPairOfObjects` reference.

Hence I can do,

```
Pair<Object> pairOfObjects = listOfPairOfObjects.get(0);
```

Now, since a `Pair<Number>` was added to the list in the method, **I will receive a `Pair<Number>` object when I expect a `Pair<Object>` reference**.

And these both are totally ***incompatible*** types. Hence the error.